# ServicesSearch an error comes in java as symbol not defined in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

**package com.intel.bluetooth.javadoc.ServicesSearch;**
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.obex.*;
//import java.util.Vector;

public class ObexPutClient {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String serverURL = null; // = "btgoep://0019639C4007:6";
    if ((args != null) && (args.length > 0)) {
        serverURL = args[0];
    }
    if (serverURL == null) {
        String[] searchArgs = null;
        // Connect to OBEXPutServer from examples
        // searchArgs = new String[] { "11111111111111111111111111111123" };
        **ServicesSearch**.main(searchArgs);
        if (ServicesSearch.serviceFound.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("OBEX service not found");
            return;
        }
        // Select the first service found
        serverURL = (String)ServicesSearch.serviceFound.elementAt(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverURL);

    ClientSession clientSession = (ClientSession) Connector.open(serverURL);
    HeaderSet hsConnectReply = clientSession.connect(null);
    if (hsConnectReply.getResponseCode() != ResponseCodes.OBEX_HTTP_OK) {
        System.out.println("Failed to connect");
        return;
    }

    HeaderSet hsOperation = clientSession.createHeaderSet();
    hsOperation.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, "Hello.txt");
    hsOperation.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, "text");

    //Create PUT Operation
    Operation putOperation = clientSession.put(hsOperation);

    // Send some text to server
    byte data[] = "Hello world!".getBytes("iso-8859-1");
    OutputStream os = putOperation.openOutputStream();
    os.write(data);
    os.close();

    putOperation.close();

    clientSession.disconnect(null);

    clientSession.close();
}
```

}

Can anyone help me?The error is in bold letters.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `ServicesSearch` created? Or included? and imported (in case it exists in some other package).

Show us the code, and tell us more.